# What is the most useful sine wave oscillator circuit?

Tags: circuit-design, oscillator, microphone, speakers, sine

I need to obtain two different pure sine wave with frequencies 3kHz and 5kHz. Only allowed components: all type of op-amps, resistor, capacitor, inductors, diode, transistor. 
Sine waves will be transmitted through speaker and received by microphone so amplitude of wave should be high. 
Which sine wave oscillator circuit design I should use?

Comment: It depends on you specs!  Vout pp, Zs = [ohms] , THD ( total harmonic distortion ) [-dB]. Now if you define these, an answer is possible. Now why 3k:5kHz?

Comment: Phase shift oscillator is simple and reliable. Wien bridge is also popular but may be a bit more tricky. Use a separate power amplifier if you want to drive a speaker.

Comment: I did not down vote, but if you answer my questions, +1

Comment: Hey Tony, I have a term project and there is specifications it must be 3kHz and 5 kHz. I need Vp depends on speaker and microphone type and the distance between them so I dont know now. I have no idea about THD

Comment: Of course I research and as you see I try to find the best option. I have many options and I try to find the most useful by asking people experienced before. What is wrong? It is just a little part of a project.

Comment: What is your "useful" metric? Minimum number of components? Minimum THD? Maximum output power level? Minimum speaker impedance for a given power level and distortion level? As stated, there is simply no way to answer your question, since "most useful" is a completely undefined term.

Comment: I need maximum Vout amplitude and minimum noise.

Comment: "Most useful" is clearly opinion-based.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Keep in mind that questions about optimization require a definition about what problem dimensions are to be optimized for your application, such as size, speed, energy consumpation, user experience, etc. Since these can't be optimized all at once, you need to have a good idea of which ones are most important to you, and be able to articulate that clearly to us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me, the most simple and reliable sinus oscillator with a relatively good signal quality is the WIEN-type oscillator - amplitude stabilized using two anti-parallel diodes.

The circuit diagram of this oscillator can be found in all relevant textbooks and (of course) in the internet using the key word "WIEN oscillator".

Answer (score 1):

As far as the oscillator goes, there are some options (phase shift ones)—you pick what you feel best matches your application. You may consider the "Bubba Oscillator", for example. It looks like this:

[image]

Where the frequency of oscillation is determined by the components labeled as \$R\$ and \$C\$.

Take a look a the following [paper](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slyt164/slyt164.pdf) from TI, it shows other configurations, including the one in this answer.

Comment: Don`t use the phase shift oscillator in Fig. 6 of the mentioned TI paper. It is a bad circuit since the RC sections are loaded by the inverting amplifier. There are better solutions for phase-shift topologies.

Comment: @LvW Thanks for the heads-up, you're exactly right about that! As a side note, I like your answers on Opamps circuits (:

Comment: Sixcab, thank you. A short remark to the topology in Fig. 8 of the TI paper (quadrature oscillator). This oscillator does NOT need any additional non-linearity (e.g. diodes) for amplitude limiting. There will be only a very small clipping effect. The reason (the background) for this surprising result is not described in any textbook (as far as I know).